# How to enable play pause functionality in this jquery 3d slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am using 3d slider to display the slider in one of my website.
I need to apply the the play/pause functionality in it. So please let me know how can I add into it.

Here is HTML :-

```
<section id="dg-container" class="dg-container">
            <div class="dg-wrapper">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image01"><div>http://www.colazionedamichy.it/</div></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="image02"><div>http://www.percivalclo.com/</div></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="image03"><div>http://www.wanda.net/fr</div></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="image04"><div>http://lifeingreenville.com/</div></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="image05"><div>http://circlemeetups.com/</div></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="image06"><div>http://www.castirondesign.com/</div></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="image07"><div>http://www.foundrycollective.com/</div></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt="image08"><div>http://www.mathiassterner.com/home</div></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/9.jpg" alt="image09"><div>http://learnlakenona.com/</div></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/10.jpg" alt="image10"><div>http://www.neighborhood-studio.com/</div></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/11.jpg" alt="image11"><div>http://www.beckindesign.com/</div></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/12.jpg" alt="image12"><div>http://kicksend.com/</div></a>
            </div>
            <nav>   
                <span class="dg-prev">&lt;</span>
                <span class="dg-pause">||</span>
                <span class="dg-next">&gt;</span>
            </nav>
        </section>
```

And this is JS I am using for it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#dg-container').gallery();
    });
</script/>
```

I am following [`this`](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/06/3d-gallery-with-css3-and-jquery/) tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I think this following code will make your work easier.

```
     <button id="pause" onclick="pauseFunction()">
    </button>
<button id="play" onclick="playFunction()"></button>
```

And add below functions

```
    function pauseFunction(){
    $('#dg-container').gallery({autoplay:false});
  clearTimeout($.data( $('#dg-container')[0], 'gallery' ).slideshow);

}
function  playFunction(){
  $('#dg-container').gallery({autoplay:true});
    $.data( $('#dg-container')[0], 'gallery' )._startSlideshow();
}
```

I hope this will help to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

After checking the documentation there is possibility to add auto play and pause functionality. 
You will add two buttons Play and Pause

```
<button id="play" onclick="playFunction">Play</button>
<button id="pause" onclick="pauseFunction">Pause</button>
```

Play button will start function playFunction()

```
playFunction(){
  $('#dg-container').gallery({autoplay:true});
}
pauseFunction(){
  $('#dg-container').gallery({autoplay:false});
}
```

### **EDIT**

If its not working then you can click next button programatically

```
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
```

Play button will start function playFunction()

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  $(".dg-next").click(); 
}, 5000);
```

This will press next after button every 5 sec.

Comment: This code is to give you an idea. 
I typed it without testing.
Basically idea is to attach function to next button This function will be clicked programatically using timer.
assign id to next previous if class is not working

Comment: This will work as this is simple clicking on next button after a fixed time interval.
This interval functionality will be enable when you press play button.

Answer (score 2):

To stop pause the autoplay, we need to **clear the timeout** given by the framework i.e.:

```
clearTimeout($.data( $('#dg-container')[0], 'gallery' ).slideshow);
```

to start the paused slideshow again call `_startSlideshow()`

```
$.data( $('#dg-container')[0], 'gallery' )._startSlideshow();
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the tutorial you followed, you will see that there are some options available such as autoplay, interval etc. I suggest you to make play and pause buttons and in the click event listener of these function, change the autoplay to true/false and re-initialize the slider.

**click function of play button**

```
$('#dg-container').gallery({autoplay:true});
```

**click function of pause button**

```
$('#dg-container').gallery({autoplay:false});
```